# Wearing Gold Shoes Halal or Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, gold

I'm interested in buying a Buscemi Sneaker but I am worried if it is halal to wear it since it has a clip covered in gold as its accessory. 
I normally avoid wearing silk and gold products but I am not sure if this qualifies as haram?

Comment: Is it real gold or just colored gold?  Buscemi sneakers don't come with pure gold accessories...

Comment: They are gold plated not pure gold

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine, even if it is pure gold. In Islam, Gold is forbidden to wear in large quantity for men, however, if the item is composed of mostly non gold and has some gold in it it should be fine as the Prophet PBUH [mentions](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/36/26):

> حَدَّثَنَا حُمَيْدُ بْنُ مَسْعَدَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا إِسْمَاعِيلُ، حَدَّثَنَا خَالِدٌ، عَنْ مَيْمُونٍ الْقَنَّادِ، عَنْ أَبِي قِلاَبَةَ، عَنْ مُعَاوِيَةَ بْنِ أَبِي سُفْيَانَ، أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم نَهَى عَنْ رُكُوبِ النِّمَارِ وَعَنْ لُبْسِ الذَّهَبِ إِلاَّ مُقَطَّعًا ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو دَاوُدَ أَبُو قِلاَبَةَ لَمْ يَلْقَ مُعَاوِيَةَ ‏.‏
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) forbade to ride on panther skins and to wear gold except a little.

Comment: I mostly agree with your answer. I have one remark. IMO women wear gold mainly for beautification purposes where as for men wearing large quantity of Gold implies pompousness. Since main emphasis of Religion is bring out humility in both men and women, any and all displays of arrogance are discouraged for both men and women. Same goes for panther skins. I would further add that IMO in todays world pomposity that comes with wearing large qunatity of gold has been replaced by wearing apparels of a certain brands. If somebody is wearing such articles only to show off, then it is also undesirable.